# Hide a Manipulate slider conditionally

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I want to hide over's control if len is higher than 15.

`ControlType -> None`

isn't doing what I want. Why?

```
Manipulate[len, {len, 10, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},

 {over, 0, 30,  1, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ControlType -> If[len  > 15, None, Slider]}]
```

Answer (score 8):

This is a simpler version. I keep the older version below for reference.

[image]

```
Manipulate[{len, over},

 Dynamic[If[len > 15,

   Control[{{len, 10, "len"}, 10, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", Slider}],

   Grid[{
     {Control[{{len, 10, "len"}, 10, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled",Slider}]},
     {Control[{{over, 10, "over"}, 0, 30, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled", Slider}]}
     }
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

**Old answer**

[image]

```
Manipulate[{len, over},

 Grid[{
   {Text@"Len", Manipulator[Dynamic[len, {len = #} &], {10, 20, 1}], 
    Dynamic@len},

   {Dynamic@If[len > 15,
      Invisible@
       Row[{Text@"over", Manipulator[Dynamic[over, {over = #} &], {0, 30, 1}], over}],

      Row[{Text@"over", Manipulator[Dynamic[over, {over = #} &], {0, 30, 1}], over}]
      ], SpanFromLeft
    }
   }, Spacings -> {1, 1}
  ],

 {{len, 10}, None},
 {{over, 10}, None}
 ]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to still do that by defining a grid in a different cell? Here's the main question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250140/external-dynamic-control-with-manipulate

Answer (score 5):

I prefer Nasser's original answer because I don't like a manipulate panel that changes size every time the 'over' slider disappears and reappears. However, I would suggest the following simplification to its code.

```
Manipulate[
  Row[{"length ", length, "  over ", over}],
  Dynamic @ Column[
    {Control[{{length, 10}, 10, 20, 1, AppearanceElements -> All}],
     If[length > 15, Invisible, Identity] @
       Control[{{over, 15}, 0, 30, 1, AppearanceElements -> All}]}]]
```

[image: under]

[image: over]