# External Dynamic Control with Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

I want to have dynamic controls that depend on other controls. For example, the code

```
Manipulate[use,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Use slider", Control[{{use, False, ""}, {True, False}}]},
    If[use,
     {"Slider", Control[{{sli, 10, ""}, 1, 100}]},
     Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]
    }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}]]
```

allows me to have the slider control only when the control checkbox is ticked

[image]

[image]

Since I have a huge control grid, I was wondering if it's possible to define the controls outside `Manipulate`, in a different cell, and call them from within `Manipulate`. I tried defining

```
cont =
  Grid[{
     {"Use slider", Control[{{use, False, ""}, {True, False}}]},
     If[use,
      {"Slider", Control[{{sli, 10, ""}, 1, 100}]},
      Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]
     }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}];
```

and then simply write

```
Manipulate[use, Dynamic@cont]
```

However, even though I can update the box, the slider remains hidden. Alternatively, I tried to set `cont = Dynamic@Grid ...` but, in this case, when I check the box, the slider appears only for a brief moment. It flashes and then disappears. The box remains unticked in this case.

It must be related to how `Dynamic` works but I'm not sure how to solve this.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Following Lukas Lang's answer below, I wrote a `Manipulate` version for the case of controls with customized names. For example, with two sliders we have

```
Attributes[cont] = {HoldAll};
    cont[vis_, sli1_, sli2_] :=
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Use slider", Checkbox@Dynamic@vis},
    If[vis,
     Sequence @@ {
       {"Slider 1", Slider[Dynamic@sli1, {0, 100}]},
       {"Slider 2", Slider[Dynamic@sli2, {0, 50}]}},
     Nothing]},
   Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}]
```

and, using `Manipulate` and removing the panels, we may write

```
Manipulate[Dynamic[{vis1, sli1, sli2}],
 Column@{Column@
    {cont[vis1, sli1, sli2]}},
 FrameMargins -> 0,
 Initialization :> ({vis1 = False, sli1 = 20, sli2 = 20})]
```

Comment: all dynamic variables inside the `Manipulate` are localized. You need mark them as global to make them interacting with outside code. Look onto the `LocalizeVariables`

Comment: I've set `LocalizeVariables` to false, but no change. I also tried defining the outside controls as a function with no arguments, but that also doesn't seem to do it. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `Manipulate` by default localizes the variables. But instead of trying to disable the localization, I would suggest you use custom controls to achieve what you want:

```
icont[Dynamic@var_] := Dynamic@Grid[
   {
    {"Use slider", Checkbox@Dynamic@var[[1]]},
    If[var[[1]], {"Slider", Slider[Dynamic@var[[2]], {0, 100}]}, Nothing]
    }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}
   ]
cont = icont[#] &;
```

This defines a function `cont` that will produce a control of the desired type when a variable of the form `Dynamic[var]` is passed to it (which is what `Manipulate` does). The second definition is needed since `Manipulate` only accepts expressions with head `Function` for custom controls, so we simply return one that calls the actual code.

You can then use this inside `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 sli,
 {{sli, {True, 10}}, cont}
 ]
```

[image]

Note that I set the variable to a two-element list that contains both the checkbox value and the slider value. This is because `Manipulate` only provides us with a single variable per control, so it needs to perform double-duty.

If you don't care about the checkbox state outside of your custom control, you can do the following:

```
icont[Dynamic@var_] := DynamicModule[{vis = True}, Dynamic@Grid[
    {
     {"Use slider", Checkbox@Dynamic@vis},
     If[vis, {"Slider", Slider[Dynamic@var, {0, 100}]}, Nothing]
     }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}
    ]
  ]
cont = icont[##] &;

Manipulate[
 sli,
 {{sli, {True, 10}}, cont}
 ]
```

[image]

Here, we use a [`DynamicModule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html) to localize the visibility toggle manually.

You can also take advantage of the fact that `Manipulate` will pass the limits to the custom function if they are given:

```
icont[Dynamic@var_, lims_ : {0, 100}] := Dynamic@Grid[
   {
    {"Use slider", Checkbox@Dynamic@var[[1]]},
    If[var[[1]], {"Slider", Slider[Dynamic@var[[2]], lims]}, Nothing]
    }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}
   ]
cont = icont[##] &;

Manipulate[
 sli,
 {{sli, {True, 10}}, 0, 200, cont}
 ]
```

[image]

If you need even more control, I would suggest avoiding `Manipulate` completely and to go directly with `DynamicModule`:

```
Attributes[cont] = {HoldAll};
cont[vis_, sli_, lims_ : {0, 100}] := Dynamic@Grid[
   {
    {"Use slider", Checkbox@Dynamic@vis},
    If[vis, {"Slider", Slider[Dynamic@sli, {0, 100}]}, Nothing]},
   Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}
   ]
```

The above version of `cont` can be whatever we want since we don't have to make it compatible with `Manipulate`, and so we can then easily pass several variables and settins. To use it, we build our own "UI":

```
DynamicModule[
 {
  vis1 = False, sli1 = 20,
  vis2 = True, sli2 = 30
  },
 Panel[
  Column@
   {
    Column@{
      cont[vis1, sli1],
      cont[vis2, sli2, {0, 200}]
      },
    Panel@Dynamic[
      {vis1, vis2, sli1, sli2}
      ]
    }
  ],
 FrameMargins -> 0
 ]
```

[image]

If you really want to use `Manipulate` (e.g. because you want "normal" controls as well as your custom ones), you can use the following. As a baseline, I use the control from the updated question:

```
Attributes[cont] = {HoldAll};
cont[vis_, sli1_, sli2_] := Dynamic@Grid[{
  {"Use slider", Checkbox@Dynamic@vis}, 
  If[vis, 
    Sequence @@ {
      {"Slider 1", Slider[Dynamic@sli1, {0, 100}]}, 
      {"Slider 2", Slider[Dynamic@sli2, {0, 50}]}
    }, Nothing]
  }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}
]
```

The `Manipulate` itself would look like this:

```
Manipulate[
 {vis1, sli1, sli2},
 {{vis1, False}, None},
 {{sli1, 20}, None},
 {{sli2, 20}, None},
 Item@cont[vis1, sli1, sli2],
 FrameMargins -> 0
 ]
```

[image]

While in principle, the solution in the question "works", it's a bit pointless in the sense that manipulate does nothing but provide some styling. This is because `Manipulate` does not know about the variables at all, so e.g. the bookmarks and the initialization after the kernel was killed will not work. In contrast, the above solution explicitly tells `Manipulate` about the variables and their initial values, and tells it to not display a control for them. We are then free to add a custom expression as control, in the form `Item[control]`.

Sidenote: As you can see, the `Dynamic` around the first argument of `Manipulate` is not needed, since `Manipulate` effectively wraps the first argument in `Dynamic` anyway.

If you find the above syntax distracting, you can write your own wrapper for `Manipulate` that declares all the dummy variables based on a list you provide:

```
Attributes[customManipulate] = {HoldAll};
customManipulate[expr_, {vars___}, controls___] :=
 Replace[
   Hold[vars],
   {
    HoldPattern[var_ = init_] :> {{var, init}, None},
    var_ :> {var, None}
    },
   1
   ] /. Hold[v___] :> Manipulate[
    expr,
    v,
    controls
    ]
```

You use it as:

```
customManipulate[
 {vis1, sli1, sli2},
 {vis1 = False, sli1 = 20, sli2 = 20},
 Item@cont[vis1, sli1, sli2],
 FrameMargins -> 0
 ]
(* same result as above *)
```

Note however that the coloring of the variable names no longer works like this:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to specify each of the controls instead of using `var`? My code has lots of controls and I'm afraid that using a list would be confusing after a while. Great answer nonetheless!

Comment: @samwolfe I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you asking for a way to just give `Manipulate` a list of things that should act as controls, without having `Manipulate` know about the variables?

Comment: As far as I understood, you are listing the variables by setting `var[[1]]`, `var[[2]]` and so on. Instead of using these, I would like them to have custom names, like `use` and `sli` in my code. Your answer does what I want, but I specifically want to give `Manipulate` a list of controls which initial values and "variable names" I can edit within `cont` (or `icont`, in your case). I think writing `icont[Dynamic@use_,Dynamic@sli_]` could work, but your initial values are still inside `Manipulate`.

Comment: Essentially, how do I rename the `var` entries so that I can more easily track the variables?

Comment: @samwolfe The variables are actually always created in pairs, so e.g. `Manipulate[{sli1,sli2},{{sli1, {True, 10}}, cont},{{sli2, {True, 10}}, cont}]` would result in variables `sli1[[1]]`,`sli1[[2]]` for the first control, and `sli2[[1]]`,`sli2[[2]]` for the second control. So if you can live with the visibility toggle and the slider having a common name, I'd suggest you keep it like that. If you really need completely separate names for the two variables for the slider and checkbox, let me know, then I'll write up one approach that comes to mind (even if it's not the nicest)

Comment: I would really need completely separate names because I have many variables (many of which dependent on other variables). It would just be much easier to keep track. I've been trying to do it but with no success so far, so if you could show me I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @samwolfe Does the updated answer (at the very bottom) help with your issues?

Comment: Brilliant! I would indeed prefer to use `Manipulate`, any reason not to? I wrote a version of your code using `Manipulate` in the edited question. Take a look and let me know what you think, or whether I could improve something. Thank you nonetheless for this discussion, you were really helpful! :)

Comment: @samwolfe I have added another solution to the bottom along the lines of what you show in your update in the question. As noted, your solution "works" but doesn't really benefit at all from using `Manipulate`. The newly added part above shows how to make it work "more properly"